# Extending the OSFONTDIR environment variable on Win 10 to include user fonts

Tags: fonts, windows, environment-variables, kpathsea

I am trying to use some fonts I have installed as a user on Windows 10, but XeLaTeX cannot find them. The fonts have been installed in `C:\Users\<My User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`.

As I understand it, I need to extend the variable `OSFONTDIR` to include this directory. Of course, I still want system fonts to be searched after my own.

Before my attempts, this was the value of the variable (output in PowerShell):

```
> kpsewhich --var-value=OSFONTDIR 
C:/Windows/fonts//
> $env:OSFONTDIR
<empty>
```

I then tried setting `OSFONTDIR` to

```
C:\Users\<My User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts:
```

in the appropriate dialog in Windows.

From reading the docs, I thought that adding a colon at the end of the path would ensure both user fonts and system fonts are searched, but kpsewhich now returns:

```
> kpsewhich --var-value=OSFONTDIR
C:/Users/<My User>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts:
```

I also tried to append to the variable the way I would in bash under Linux, using

```
C:/Users/<My User>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts:%OSFONTDIR%
```

At the moment I can only search one directory OR the other. What syntax should I be using to search both?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: windows doesn't use a colon try with `;`.

Answer (score 1):

I have windows 10 and use some of the system fonts. With `xelatex`   and `lualatex` you have to use the correct name of the files to define each `\newfontfamily`, which is not some fancy name windows or word shows you. The real file name of installed fonts do not have spaces in them. You need to look  in the `\Windows\Fonts` directory, click over the family to see  all the files and with the right button over one choose `Properties`.

In this example I am using three fonts that came with my windows installation to show how the various shapes can be specified.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program =xelatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
    
\newfontfamily\berlinfamily[%Berlins Sans FB
Extension = .ttf,%
BoldFont = *DB,%
UprightFont=*R,%
]{BRLNS}

\newfontfamily\segoefamily[% Segoe UI
Extension = .ttf,%
UprightFont=*,%
BoldFont = *B,%
ItalicFont=*I,%
BoldItalicFont = *Z,
]{SEGOEUI}  

\newfontfamily\magneto{MAGNETOB.TTF}% Magneto Bold

\newcommand{\ABC}{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z}

\newcommand{\abc}{a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    The Berlin Large normal font \\
    {\berlinfamily\Large \ABC\\ }
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    The font in its normal size \\
    {\berlinfamily \ABC} \\
    and the Computer Modern Roman for comparison \\
\ABC 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    The Segoe Huge bold font \\
    {\segoefamily\Huge\bfseries \ABC\\ }
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    The Segoe Huge bold italic font \\
    {\segoefamily\Huge\bfseries\slshape \abc\\  }
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    The Magneto Bold \\
    {\magneto\Huge \ABC\\  }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has helped in the past, so I generally load fonts in XeTeX documents using the file name (including the extension), but this wasn't the issue here, it was a path question.

Comment: BTW, I have had luck renaming ttf font files with weird names, and then running  mktexlsr.exe (under cygwin, running as admin). But that wasn't the problem here.